# Multivariate time series, detect anomalies, Keras

Tags: python, keras, time-series, anomaly-detection

I am currently facing a task in which I need to **recognize the presence of anomalies in instances, each described by multiple time series**.
Each anomaly may be 10 seconds long, or more (typically, less than a couple of minutes).

Specifically, this is the situation:

- each instance is characterized by 10 time series
- given an instance, each time series describes the same time interval (typically, 8-10 hours)
- all instances are characterized by the same kind of 10 time series
- each time series has a sampling rate (number of observations per second)
- the class labels are very unbalanced: anomalies may cover around 5% of the entire time interval described by the series, if present at all
- finally, for each instance, **I have a hand-made labelling, telling me which time intervals are "anomalous"**

I would like to train a model on a set of labelled instances, capable of recognizing the presence of anomalous intervals in a new, previously unobserved, instance.

The first approach that I have tried is based on windowing: given a training instance, I simply apply a "moving window" on each time series (e.g., 10 seconds long), and I calculate some measures on the values belonging to the window (e.g., average, min, max, variance, entropy, energy, ... I use TsFresh library for such a task). Then, I mark each window as "anomalous" or not, based on the hand-made labelling (specifically, if there is an anomaly which overlaps the 95% of the window, then I mark it as anomalous).

As a result, the training set is made by instances of the form, e.g.:
[average_ts_1, min_ts_1, max_ts_1, ..., average_ts_10, min_ts_10, max_ts_10, LABEL]

Although this approach is giving me some encouraging results, **I would like to deal with the time series data directly**, so not to lose any potential information.
In such case, I think that the task would become: given 10 time series as input, predict another time series made just by 1s and 0s. Such predicted time series would cover the same time period as the time series given as input, and would tell me in which intervals the anomaly is present or not (e.g., with a 1-second granularity).

Now, finally, the question: is there any (deep) learning architecture that I could use for such a task?

Currently, I am working with Python, relying on XGBoost with the windowing techique.
I have also some experience with Keras, but I am open to any suggestion.

Comment: Any update or did your research lead to anything fruitful or worth sharing?

Comment: I have tried with the saliency maps provided by keras-vis, but until now I have not been successful in applying them to 1D convolutions. 
As suggested by Luca Angioloni, the most useful thing to do would be that of trying to find the input that maximises the positive class, but I still have to figure out how to do that.